How to implement self defined request attributes in TYPO3 extensions
TYPO3 12 and later use request attributes to store internal informations.
How does it work to add self defined attributes in TYPO3 extensions? I could not find anything in the docs.
Request Attributes
TYPO3/typo3_src-13.2.1/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/ServerRequest.php:
namespace TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http;

class ServerRequest extends Request implements ServerRequestInterface
{
    protected array $attributes = [];


This is a replacement for:  Breaking: #102600 TSFE->applicationData removed

You can use a PSR-15 Middleware to achive that.
All you need is a Middleware class like:
Classes/Middleware/RequestEnrichingMiddleware.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VENDOR\ExtName\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class RequestEnrichingMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{

    public function process(
        ServerRequestInterface $request,
        RequestHandlerInterface $handler,
    ): ResponseInterface {

        $myCustomDataArray = [
            'Foo' => 'Bar',
            'Foooo' => 'Baar',
        ];

        $request = $request->withAttribute('myCustomDataArray', $myCustomDataArray);

        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}

And then you must register this middleware in:
Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php
<?php

return [
    'frontend' => [
        'vendor/my-middleware-identifier' => [
            'target' => \VENDOR\ExtName\Middleware\RequestEnrichingMiddleware::class,
            'after' => [
                'typo3/cms-core/response-propagation',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

For more information see:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Middlewares.html#enriching-the-request

You can also use a class as your custom Attribute. We like that more because its better typed and you can enforce datatypes and your IDE knows about the properties

This is helpful. I have implemented it successfully in the tt_board 1.16.1 extension: Submit.php (called from tslib_fetce and Form.php.

You can use withAttribute in PSR middlewares to enrich the request. This isn't really TYPO3 specific, but a general PSR approach. See:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Middlewares.html#enriching-the-request
You can set/get any attribute (don't use a name that TYPO3 already uses though).

Is there any recommendation for a TYPO3 extension? I mean, maybe the extension key should be part of the attribute name in order to avoid possible conflicts with other extensions.

Sounds like a good idea, yes. I know of no special recommendation yet.
